# Thickbox - Is there a "onready" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, thickbox

I use a thickbox to display some html content in a modal window.

I know the thickbox component is flagged as "not maintained, please try another component", but I don't have a choice on using it.

The html content is loaded through the documented "AJAX content" method :

```
<a href="ajax/ctnt?value1=10&value2=12&width=640&height=480" 
   class="thickbox">
       click me
</a>
```

All of this works fine with simple html, a modal window pops with the correct content on my page.

My question :
I would like to initialize a jquery component inside the modal window after it has loaded.
e.g. :

```
$('.actDisplay').click( displayAction );
```

[EDIT]

I also need to initialize other javascript components. For example, I use [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) to display the agenda of a week.

In order to initialize this component, I have to call

```
$('#agendaDiv').fullcalendar( options );
```

once the DOM is loaded.

[/EDIT]

Do you see some standard javascript or jquery event I could plug into to have this code executed after the DOM of the ajax answer has been loaded ?

For a full page, I would put it in the `$(document).ready` event. But in this case ?

Thanks in advance,

*G*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jquery **live** method

```
$('.actDisplay').live('click', displayAction);
```

or inject a <script> tag at the end of your loaded content (possibily a [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/))

Comment: Thks, your answer solves part of my problem. Actually, I have extra stuff to do after loading the frame. See edit in my question. Do you have a suggestion as to how to do this cleanly ?

Comment: What about the second part of Riccardo's answer (about injecting a script tag at the end of the resource that will trigger a custom event)? Won't it help you?